# How to perform operation on grouped records?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

This is my records:

```
Id    EmpName        Stats
  1      Abc            1000  
  1      Abc            3000
  1      Abc            2000
  2      Pqr            4000
  2      Pqr            5000  
  2      Pqr            6000
  2      Pqr            7000
```

I am trying to group by on Id fields and after doing group by i want output like this:

**Expected output**:

```
Id   EmpName     Stats
1     Abc        3000
2     Pqr        3000
```

For 1st output record calculation is like this:

```
3000 - 1000=2000  (i.e subtract highest - lowest from 1st and 2nd records)
3000 - 2000=1000  (i.e subtract highest - lowest from 2nd and 3rd records)

Total=2000 + 1000 =3000


For 2nd output record calculation is like this:
5000 - 4000=1000  (i.e subtract highest - lowest from first two records)
6000 - 5000=1000  
7000 - 6000=1000
total=1000 + 1000=2000
```

This is 1 sample fiddle i have created:[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ckPXiu)

So far i have manage to group records by id but now how do i perform this calculation on group records??

Comment: I would suggest doing this in a simple `foreach` loop instead of linq.

Comment: @ShaunakD:Any reason for this??

Comment: The operations required are much complicated to be included in a single linq query. It would require multiple selects and aggregate functions like `Max`.

Comment: @ShaunakD:Ok so if use foreach loop then how i would group by records??

Comment: @Learning You can iterate over an IQueryable which you filtered (and grouped by in your case) first.

Comment: @ThibaultFouquaert:But how i will access those grouped records if i iterate my first id say Id=1??

Comment: What is the expected `total` when the group contains single element?

Comment: @IvanStoev:In that case it will be Stats value only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate(v=vs.110).aspx) method overload that allows you to maintain custom accumulator state.

In your case, we'll be maintaining the following:

```
decimal Sum; // Current result
decimal Prev; // Previous element Stats (zero for the first element)
int Index; // The index of the current element
```

The `Index` is basically needed just to avoid accumulating the first element `Stats` into the result.

And here is the query:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(t => t.Id)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        ID = g.Key,
        Name = g.First().EmpName,
        Stats = g.Aggregate(
            new { Sum = 0m, Prev = 0m, Index = 0 },
            (a, e) => new
            {
                Sum = (a.Index < 2 ? 0 : a.Sum) + Math.Abs(e.Stats - a.Prev),
                Prev = e.Stats,
                Index = a.Index + 1
            }, a => a.Sum)
    }).ToList();
```

**Edit:** As requested in the comments, here is the `foreach` equivalent of the above `Aggregate` usage:

```
static decimal GetStats(IEnumerable<Employee> g)
{
    decimal sum = 0;
    decimal prev = 0;
    int index = 0;
    foreach (var e in g)
    {
        sum = (index < 2 ? 0 : sum) + Math.Abs(e.Stats - prev);
        prev = e.Stats;
        index++;        
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: ok your query is working perfect but could you please explain me your solution if you dont mind??

Comment: Sure. You know that the `g` variable additionally to `Key` property is enumerable containing the elements with that key, so `Aggregate` is processing the elements of each group. The first argument is the initial state I was talking about, the second lambda is called for each element, receiving the current element and the previous state. You apply some logic and return a new state. The last lambda is called after the loop, passing the last state, and we extract just the result (other members were just for processing). You can think of it like initial block, foreach block and final code block.

Comment: actually i have never used aggregate function and was trying to understand your code but you have written it in very professional way so as a newbie i was struggling to understand it.just 1 request if i have to modify it and write it using foreach(just for my understanding) how i could write???

Comment: No problem, there you go.

Comment: Can you help me with this question or any suggestions or idea anything if you have related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924709/getting-concurrency-error-on-updating-record-with-data-adapter

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, like mentioned in my comment, this can be done using a single linq query but would have many complications, one being unreadable code.

Using a simple `foreach` on the `IGrouping` List,

Updated (handle dynamic group length):

```
var list = CreateData();
var groupList = list.GroupBy(t => t.Id);

var finalList = new List<Employee>();

//Iterate on the groups
foreach(var grp in groupList){
    var part1 = grp.Count()/2;
    var part2 = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)grp.Count()/2);
    var firstSet = grp.Select(i=>i.Stats).Take(part2);
    var secondSet = grp.Select(i=>i.Stats).Skip(part1).Take(part2);
    var total = (firstSet.Max() - firstSet.Min()) + (secondSet.Max() - secondSet.Min());
    finalList.Add(new Employee{
        Id = grp.Key,
        EmpName = grp.FirstOrDefault().EmpName,
        Stats = total
    });

}
```

*Note -

*You can optimize the logic used in getting the data for calculation.*

*More complicated logic is to divide the group into equal parts in case it is not fixed.*

**[Updated Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y786vw)**

---

The LinQ way,

```
var list = CreateData();
var groupList = list.GroupBy(t => t.Id);
var testLinq = (from l in list
                group l by l.Id into grp
                let part1 = grp.Count()/2
                let part2 = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)grp.Count()/2)
                let firstSet = grp.Select(i=>i.Stats).Take(part2)
                let secondSet = grp.Select(i=>i.Stats).Skip(part1).Take(part2)
                select new Employee{
                    Id = grp.Key,
                    EmpName = grp.FirstOrDefault().EmpName,
                    Stats = (firstSet.Max() - firstSet.Min()) + (secondSet.Max() - secondSet.Min())
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: If i'm not mistaken this will only work when you have 3 records per group by?

Comment: @ThibaultFouquaert, Yes exactly. Which is why I added a note that this is just a simple example. May be I should be more clear. Editing my answer.

Comment: i have tried your solution and it works fine in case of 3 grouped records but when i take 4 grouped records or more than it then it doesnt works.see my updated question and thanks for the solution